# rspec should include tries to chomp an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

Using Rails 3.2.2, I just installed rspec and tried my first test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Mains" do
  describe "GET index" do
    it "gets the page which has the proper content" do
      get 'index.html'
      response.status.should be(200)
      response.body.should include("one")
    end
  end
end
```

When I run the spec I get

```
Failures:

  1) Mains GET index gets the page which has the proper content
     Failure/Error: response.body.should include("one")
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `chomp' for ["one"]:Array
```

This comes strait out of [Ryan Bates' Railscast 257](http://railscasts.com/episodes/257-request-specs-and-capybara), so I'm a bit lost

thanks in advance,

Comment: How is your index view and controller action look like?

Comment: same bug here when the word in the include matcher does not exist. maybe a bug in rspec.

Answer (score 4):

**[EDIT] The issue is [corrected](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/issues/130) in `rspec-expectations`, on `master` branch. You can fix it by using this in your `Gemfile`:**

```
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.9'
gem 'rspec-expectations', :git => "https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations.git", :branch => 'master'
```

I encountered the same issue on `Rails 3.0.12` with `rspec 2.9.0`. Reverting to `rspec 2.8.0` / `rspec-rails 2.8.1` did the trick.

I raised [an issue on Github](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/issues/130), `rspec/rspec-expectations`, we'll see if it's really a bug.

*For reference, this is the step definition:*

```
Then /^(?:I|they) should see "([^"]*?)" in the email body$/ do |text|
  current_email.default_part_body.to_s.should include(text)
end
```

... the step in the feature:

```
step %{I should see "changer de mot de passe" in the email body}
```

... which was raising:

```
undefined method `chomp' for ["changer de mot de passe"]:Array (NoMethodError)
  ./features/step_definitions/email_steps.rb:110:in `/^(?:I|they) should see "([^"]*?)" in the email body$/'
```